# How to access an Angular App created on CentOs7 in a Windows 10 VM?

Tags: linux, centos, windows, webserver, hostname

I created an angular app in CentOs7 and was able to open it in a web browser in my CentOs7 VM using http://localhost:4200/. I need to be able to access it my Windows 10 VM, but when I tried changing the IP, it still worked in Cent but gave me an error saying port 4200 is already in use. It doesn't work in Windows with either address. How do I configure this so it's accessible in my Windows VM?

Comment: So you have 2 VMs. One running Windows and one running Linux. The angular app is running on Linux and you need to access the app from your Windows VM. Is that right? Also let us know what hypervisor you are using, VMWare, VirtualBox or something else?

Comment: Yes that is right and I am using vRealize Automation.

Comment: I have not used vRealize Automation before. But what should work for you is changing the networking options of the VMs. I believe the VMs are using NAT networking which makes both VMs invisible to one another. If you set the networking option to Bridged for your Linux VM, you should be able to access the app from your Windows VM using IP address.

Comment: Yes they are invisible to one another but setting up a bridge is not necessary, as I all I am trying to do is access the webpage for the app. for example when I open the app in a web browser in linux, the page loads since the app is running at that machine (VM), but I need to configure the app so it is accessible out the local host.

Comment: If your Linux VM is set up using NAT networking, no ports of that virtual machine will be accessible from anywhere except localhost.